# Get all threads in a guild Discord.net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I want to get all threads in a guild, what I did is the following

```
if (message.Author is SocketGuildUser socketUser)
{
    SocketGuild guild = socketUser.Guild;
    foreach (var channel in guild.Channels)
    {
        if(channel.GetType() == typeof())
        { 
            //Do code here
        }
    }
}
```

I got stuck at the typeof part, is It possible to detect if a channel is a thread? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is but you can simply use `guild.ThreadChannels` to get all thread channels in your guild.

Also `GetType()` is going to return you a data type which is being used for channels (`SocketChannel`). Method you are looking for is called `GetChannelType()` which returns an enum describing type of channel.

But in the if statement you posted you should just use

`if(channel.GetChannelType() == ChannelType.PublicThread)`

You have three types of threads.

1. `ChannelType.NewsThread`
2. `ChannelType.PrivateThread`
3. `ChannelType.PublicThread`